# Follow up and intents in Rasa NLU

Tags: rasa-nlu

Can anyone clarify how to configure follow up intents or prompts like in api.ai ? I am trying to create an application similar to api.ai using rasa nad spacy as backend.

Answer (score 5):

[Rasa NLU](http://rasa.ai/products/rasa-nlu/) is *just* for the intent and entity classification. From their website:

> Rasa NLU is an open source tool for intent classification and entity extraction. You can think of it as a set of high level APIs for building your own language parser using existing NLP and ML libraries.

To implement conversation or dialogue you need a different tool or to program your own solution.

Popular ones in the Rasa community are:

- [botkit.ai](https://www.botkit.ai)
- [Rasa Core](https://rasa.ai/products/rasa-core/)
- [Articulate](https://github.com/samtecspg/articulate)

Answer (score 1):

As Keller said, it can be done with Rasa-core. DialogFlow supports both (input) parameters and  “contexts”. Rasa also supports both (input) parameters and  contexts with “Rasa slots”.

There are three steps:

- 1) In slots section of domain.yml, you can add a context, for example:

`slots:
  zipcode:
    type: text
  request_user_affirm:
    type: text`

- 2) `request_user_affirm` is the context slot, which will be filled by a `customAction`
- 3) use the context in your stories:

`* inform{"zipcode": "78733"}
 - bot_request_affirm
* deny{"request_user_affirm": "yes"}
 - utter_request_info`

`bot_request_affirm` is the custom action which will fill the `request_user_affirm` slot. if next user intent is `deny` and `request_user_affirm` is set, than the bot will response with `utter_request_info` action.

have fun with rasa-core.

Answer (score 0):

> **RASA Core** was specifically built for this, rather than creating a
>   dialog flow with simple if-else statements, RASA Core uses machine
>   learning to decide the flow.
>
> [More Information here](https://core.rasa.ai/)